# Decomposition of socle of a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, noncommutative-algebra, socle

My question is divided by two:

"(1) Is the right socle $S_r$ of an arbitrary unital ring $R$ is decomposed as $S_r=S_1\bigoplus S_2$, where $S_1$ is the sum of all the nilpotent minimal right ideals, and $S_2$ is the sum of all the idempotent minimal right ideals?

(2) Is it true that $S_1^2=0$?"

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial answer is as follows:

**Claim:**

> Given two nilpotent minimal (nonzero) right ideals $S, T$, we have $ST=0$.

Proof of this goes as follows: $ST$ is a right ideal contained in $SR=S$, which is a minimal right ideal, so either $ST=0$ or $ST=S$. But in the latter case, it follows that $0=S\cdot 0=S(TT)=(ST)T=ST$, contradiction. Thus, we necessarily have $ST=0$.

This shows that $S_1^2=0,$ and that any sub-ideal of $S_1$ is nilpotent (more precisely, that any $S \leq S_1$ satisfies $S^2=0$).

Now, $S_2$ together with $S_1$ clearly generate $S_r$, so one has to only show that $S_1 \cap S_2=0$. So assume $X=S_1 \cap S_2\neq 0$. Then $X$ is a submodule of the semisimple module $S_2,$ hence it contains a simple submodule $0 \neq T$. Then $T \leq S_1$, hence $T^2=0$. If one shows that $(*)$ any minimal right ideal in $S_2$ still has to be idempotent, then we are done, because $T$ would have to be both nilpotent and idempotent.

However, I am not sure about the claim $(*)$: neither about how to prove it, nor whether it actually holds.

Comment: For any minimal right ideal $I$, we have $I^2=0$ or $I^2=I$. So  one could separate these two types of minimal right ideals in the "direct sum" decomposition of $S_r$. Hence I think this is enough for the "direct sum sign" between $S_1$ and $S_2$.

Comment: I am not so sure about that: You obtain $S_1$ and $S_2$ by summing up some sets of ideals. But then you have to show that the modules obtained are disjoint, i.e. that $S_1 \cap S_2=0$. But that does not follow simply because the sets of minimal ideals you summed up were disjoint: Verifying that comes down to checking the property $(*)$.

Comment: An argument that you suggest would work if the properties of the ideals "$I^2=0$" or "$I^2=I$" depended only on isomorphism class of $I$ as a simple $R$-module (then one could e.g. look at the isotypical components, and $S_1$ and $S_2$ would be both sum of some of those), but I don't think that that is necessarily the case.

Comment: To put it differently, what you suggest will work, but then you cannot be sure that the schosen complement $S_2$ of $S_1$, i.e. the sum of some of the idempotent ideals, will be equal to the sum of *all* idempotent minimal right ideals.

Comment: If $S_1\cap S_2$ is nonzero, then it contains some minimal right ideal $T$, since it is a submodule of $S_r$. Because $S_1^2=0$, we would have $T^2=0$ too. On the other hand, because $T$ is contained in $S_2$, and the latter is a sum of minimal (simple) right ideals, then we infer that $T$ must be isomorphic to one of those right ideals, and since each of them is idempotent we have $T^2=T$. Contradiction to minimality of $T$.

Comment: @karparvar The issue with this is that when you consider two minimal right ideals $S, T$ that are isomorphic as right $R$-modules and you happen to have $S^2=S,$ the only thing that you can tell about $T$ is that $ST=T$, not that $TT=T$ (think of the analogous statement for abstract modules: It's $M \simeq N,SM=M \Rightarrow SN=N$). The confusing circumstance here is that $T$ plays in the above statement a role of both the $R$-module and a right ideal of $R$.